# Position of sliding navigation menu always below header

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following `jQuery` menu which you can also find in the `JSfiddle` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/s9k31p4t/10/):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".navigation_button").on('click', function () {
    
    var $panel = $(this).next('.panel');
    if ($panel.is(':visible')) {
      $panel.add($panel.find('.panel')).slideUp(500).removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $panel.slideDown(500).addClass('active');
    }
    
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.image {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}


/* Navigation Mobile */

.navigation {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.navigation>nav {

}


.navigation>nav>ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navigation>nav>ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}


/* Navigation Button */

.navigation_button {
 width: 20%;
 height: 60%;
 float: right;
 cursor: pointer;
 
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 background-color: fuchsia;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 20%;
 margin: 4% 0;
 background-color: #333; 
}



/* Menu Content */

.menu_box {
 width: 100%;
 float: right;
 line-height: 2.0;
 
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
}

.panel{ 
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 0%;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight: bold;
 overflow: hidden;
 display:none;
}

.button_menu {
 padding-left: 1%;
 background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">

  <div class="image">
  Image
  </div> 
  
  <div class="navigation">
  
    <div class="navigation_button">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>

   <nav class="panel"> 
 
    <ul class="menu_box">
      <li class="button_menu"> 1.0 Menu </li>
      <li class="button_menu"> 2.0 Menu </li>
      <li class="button_menu"> 3.0 Menu </li>
    </ul>
  
   </nav>

  </div>
  
</div>
```

The menu works perfectly as long as the `.navigation_button` is the same size as the `.navigation`.

However, as you can see in the code above I lowered the height of the `.navigation_button` to `height: 60%;` and when I click now on the button the `.panel` will not appear below the `.header`. It will appear below the `.navigation_button`.

---

To solve this issue I tried to put `position:absolute;` to the `.panel` and then assigned the same height of the `.header` to the `.panel` but it did not work since the `.panel` slides in from the top of the page now.

Another idea I had was to close the `.header <div>` after the `.navigation_button` but once I did that the animation did not run anymore.

---

What do I need to change in my code to ensure that the `.panel` is always **exactly** below the `.header` no matter where the `.navigation_button` is positioned within the `.header`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `.panel` to be positioned below the `.header` you could set it's position as absolute and then position it 0 from the left and 100% from the top of its first non-static parent which in your case is the `.header` (it is has a position value of fixed), this will make sure the `.panel` is below the `.header` but, in your example, the `.panel` doesn't stretch to pass the blue `.navigation` element width so if you want this then set the position of the `.navigation` element as relative.

See the demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".navigation_button").on('click', function () {
    
    var $panel = $(this).next('.panel');
    if ($panel.is(':visible')) {
      $panel.add($panel.find('.panel')).slideUp(500).removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $panel.slideDown(500).addClass('active');
    }
    
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.image {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}


/* Navigation Mobile */

.navigation {
  position: relative; /* remove this if you want the panel to stretch further */
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.navigation>nav {

}


.navigation>nav>ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navigation>nav>ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}


/* Navigation Button */

.navigation_button {
 width: 20%;
 height: 60%;
 float: right;
 cursor: pointer;
 
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 background-color: fuchsia;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 20%;
 margin: 4% 0;
 background-color: #333; 
}



/* Menu Content */

.menu_box {
 width: 100%;
 float: right;
 line-height: 2.0;
 
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
}

.panel{ 
 /* changes from here...*/
 position: absolute; 
 top: 100%;
 left: 0;
 /*...here*/
 
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 0%;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight: bold;
 overflow: hidden;
 display:none;
}

.button_menu {
 padding-left: 1%;
 background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">

  <div class="image">
  Image
  </div> 
  
  <div class="navigation">
  
    <div class="navigation_button">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>

   <nav class="panel"> 
 
    <ul class="menu_box">
      <li class="button_menu"> 1.0 Menu </li>
      <li class="button_menu"> 2.0 Menu </li>
      <li class="button_menu"> 3.0 Menu </li>
    </ul>
  
   </nav>

  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I also updated it here https://jsfiddle.net/s9k31p4t/14/

Answer (score 0):

add this code to '.panel'

```
position: absolute;
top:100%;
right: 0;
```